# Why transformations in quantum mechanics are linear?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, linear-algebra, unitarity

In quantum mechanics, when we want to introduce reference frame change, we do it such that $\left|\psi'\right> = U\left|\psi\right>$. Using the fact that $\left<\psi|\psi\right>=1$, we then deduce that $U$ should be unitary.

My question is, how do we know that the transformation is a **linear** operator? Is this a postulate of quantum physics? Is it completely general?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer since I'm on mobile:

No, it's not a postulate but rather a theorem. First, clear things up a little. We want a symmetry of the theory to act as an arbitrary transformation which conserves the unitarity of our theory. A transformation which does **not** act as a symmetry of our system need not to be a linear transformation. 
Now, for symmetries, there exists a famous theorem by the mathematican Eugene Wigner, known as [Wigner's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_theorem), which states that the transformation encoding the action of this symmetry on the Hilbert space of states must be a linear transformation.

So to use your example, merely a change of reference frames is of course a symmetry and therefore by Wigner's theorem acts simply as a linear transformation.